# SSRS - Line Chart - Plotting Time of a Single Day on the X Axis

Tags: time, reporting-services, axis, ssrs-2008-r2, linechart

We are working on an SSRS report that shows the successes and failures of a user process over the course of a day.

We were asked for a line chart showing the various times of day with a line for success and a line for failure. This is the set up we have.

[image]

The X axis needs to be time of the given day in question.
How can I make the X Axis display the hours of a single day. The day itself is supplied as a parameter in the report.

This is the current field we are using to group the X axis and that is the time of day `= Hour(Fields!BookingRequestInitiatedDate.Value)` - when the success or failure occurred. This is how we are displaying it `=Format(Fields!BookingRequestInitiatedDate.Value,"hh:mm tt")`

But this isn't giving me what I need.

The Y Axis is the counter of events. This I have working correctly.

The X axis needs to be the timed intervals over the course of a given day.

*Ideally with a marker creating intervals every 2-3 hour intervals.
For example 8 am, 10 am, 12 pm ... etc.

Also only start and end when there is data in the chart -  in other words if nothing happening between 12 am and 8 am don't show those hours.*

Comment: This is a very convoluted and rambling question.  You can help us to help you by providing what you have now and a mock up of what you are trying to get to.

Comment: @iamdave is that clearer. I'm just stuck on how to set up the X axis to only show the span of time for a given day.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would add a dataset to the report that drops out exactly the data you need for this report in a tabular form, such as:

```
+------+---------+-------+
| Hour |  Type   | Value |
+------+---------+-------+
| 8am  | Success |     5 |
| 8am  | Failure |     2 |
| 10am | Success |     8 |
| 10am | Failure |     7 |
| 12pm | Success |     2 |
| 12pm | Failure |     5 |
+------+---------+-------+
```

and then use that in your chart.  Doing this allows you to very precisely filter and format your data to show the chart you need within the dataset logic (I am assuming SQL?), which will give you much more freedom than doing so in the report itself.